# How do I trigger a JavaScript confirm box without using a click event?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm working on an application that handles complaints. The user can't "close" the complaint (i.e. mark it as completed) until a batch of conditions are met. Previously, once every condition had been met, a "Close the Complaint" button would appear, but I've been asked instead to generate a confirmation window (asking, "Are you ready to close this complaint?") that would pop up as the user saves the last necessary item.

No problem, I figured. I set up JavaScript to generate the confirm window, and added attributes to the save buttons (when all of the other conditions for closure have been met) on any of the items that might be the final item necessary for closure. Except...

Once they click to save the record, they at least want to do that, whether they're ready to close the complaint or not. But currently, if they confirm "Yes," the record is saved and the complaint is closed, while if they confirm "No," then the complaint isn't closed, but neither is the record saved.

I'm working in vb.net, using Visual Studio 2008, and what I'd like to find is a way to trigger the confirm window **after** the record is saved (in the ItemInserted sub for the DetailsView). That way, it could get the confirmation and close or not, but the record would be saved either way.

Every bit of advice I can find uses button clicks to generate JavaScript confirm windows; does anybody know another way to do it?

**EDIT (adding a bit more background):**

The way I originally approached it was to make two identical save buttons. One is the ordinary button that saves the record ("ibInsert"), and the other ("ibInsertAndClose") saves, then closes the record. When the DetailsView databinds in Insert mode, I check the "ready for closure" status, then set the visibility of the buttons.

```
    If ReadyToClose() Then
     Dim ibInsertAndClose As ImageButton = CType(dvResponseDetail.FindControl("ibInsertAndClose"), ImageButton)
     Dim ibInsert As ImageButton = CType(dvResponseDetail.FindControl("ibInsert"), ImageButton)
     If Not ibInsert Is Nothing AndAlso Not ibInsertAndClose Is Nothing Then
             ibInsert.Visible = False
             ibInsertAndClose.Visible = True
             ibInsertAndClose.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: return confirm(""\nAre you ready to close this Complaint?"")")
     End If
    End If
```

Comment: What's the problem. Just include the `confirm()` code at the point in your code that you need it. Even when you see those examples that use `confirm()` in a `click` event, don't you see that it's just `confirm()` that is in the handler?

Comment: Can you please share the code that is currently triggering the JavaScript confirm window?

Comment: ignore the first "If Not ibInsert is Nothing" statement--I pasted it in twice without noticing when I was editing my comment. Thanks!

Comment: I edited it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the return from your JavaScript `confirm()` and you are able to save the record, it sounds like you have everything you need but you just need some guidance on the workflow?

Here's some pseudo-code (since I don't do .NET)

```
function saveRecord()              'saves the record
    'database code here
end function

function closeComplaint()          'closes the complaint
    'database code here
end function

function saveButtonClick()         'call this when the save button is clicked
    saveRecord()                   'fires no matter what the response is
    dim alertConfirmedTrue = ???   'response from JavaScript confirm() function
    if alertConfirmedTrue 
       then closeComplaint()       'only called if response is "ok"
end function
```

Comment: This shows how to use a `confirm()`, which is not what the OP is asking. Also, `if(response == true)` can just be `if(response)`. Or, even better `if(confirm(. . . ))`. Also, don't use `.html()` when you aren't writing any HTML. Use `.text()` for that.

Comment: It shows how to use a `confirm()` *without a click event*, which is exactly what he asked for.

Comment: I've made significant updates. My code should now match the original scenario completely, with the exception of any .net (which was not fully explained)

Comment: Sorry about my lack of specific explanation. The condition checking is the easy part; it's already done in vb.net. What I was needing was just a way to generate the confirm function for closure after the record had been saved. when I triggered it on the save button click, it lumped the save and the closure together. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: So is it working now?  If not, please post the code you have.

Comment: The way I originally approached it was to make two identical save buttons. One is the ordinary button that saves the record, and the other saves, then closes the record. When the DetailsView databinds in Insert mode, I check the "ready for closure" status, then set the visibility of the buttons:

Comment: It sounds like you might be overcomplicating this Dave. I have updated my answer, but since I don't do .NET it may not help.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like on click event you should save the record regardless then, once the save operation is complete, use a callback function to display the confirm dialog. Here's an example using `setTimeout()` instead of an actual save operation.

```js
var closureConditionsMet = true;

document.getElementById('closureRecord').addEventListener('click', function() {
  //the user clicked the record, so let's save it
  simulateSaveRecord(function() {
    if (closureConditionsMet) {
      confirm('Are you ready to close this complaint?') ? console.log('After save user clicked "OK"') : console.log('After save user clicked "Cancel"');
    } else {
      console.log('Record saved but cloure conditions have not been met');
    }

  });
});

function simulateSaveRecord(callback) {
  console.log('Waiting a few seconds for \'save\'');
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback();
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<div id="closureRecord">Pretend this is the closure record
</div>
```